# Merge the [x509] and [x.509] tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

I've just noticed that SO has two completely synonymous tags for the [X.509 public key infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509), [x509](/questions/tagged/x509) and [x.509](/questions/tagged/x.509).  They should be merged.

I'd suggest the dotted version, [x.509](/questions/tagged/x.509), as the target, since it's closer to the official name and since it's also [the name used on security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x.509).  Of course, the other name should be kept as a synonym.

(**Edit:** [SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/x509) and [SU](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/x509) seem to use the dotless spelling, so there will be some inconsistent naming across the network no matter which way the merge is done (unless, of course, those tags are renamed too).  In the absence of any other compelling reasons, however, I'd still be inclined to consider security.SE the "authoritative reference" here.  In any case, none of the other sites have nearly as many X.509 questions as SO does in absolute terms, although security.SE, being so much smaller than the trilogy sites, has by far the highest *fraction* of all its questions tagged with these tags.)

Comment: `x509` does seem to be the more popular choice though. Are you sure it shouldn't be the other way around?

Comment: @Asad: That has probably more to do with ease of typing (and the fact that many users may not even realize that periods are allowed in tag names), which doesn't really matter as long as both are kept as synonyms.  Still, see my edit to the question.